# Custom-Painting an AWT Component

Tags: java, awt, paint

I am trying to make a gradient effect on an AWT component using a series of lines drawn on its `java.awt.Component.getGraphics()` using the `java.awt.Graphics.drawLine()` method, but this never stays painted. Does anyone know how to commit these graphics to the component so they stay through resizing and other events that invoke repainting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you limited to AWT components? If not I suggest you go with Swing components (the ones starting with **"J"**. For custom painting you override the `paintComponent` method, for example:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CustomPaintingComponent extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);    // This will clear everything...

        // ... now you can apply your custom painting, for example:
        g.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);  // A line from upper left to lower right corner
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to override the paint method of the component. Otherwise, if you just use a graphics object and write lines to it a single time, the next time the component paint method is called, it will redraw over all your changes.

Comment: How can I do this? And then what is the point of the aforementioned methods?